# Geometry locus question!

Tags: geometry

Suppose that $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are two parallel lines, and there is a fixed point $P$ at the same distance from both parallels. Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are points on $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ respectively such that $\angle APB = 90^{\circ}$. Let the projection from $P$ to $\overline{AB}$ be $M$. What is the locus formed by all possible points $M$?

I just suspect it is a circle but I haven't found any formal solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "Let the projection from $P$ to $\overline{AB}$ be $M$."?

Comment: You are right, it's a circle!

Comment: Hint: you can show that is a circle of diameter equals to the distance between the lines.

Comment: How can I show that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following diagram of the situation:

[image: Final shot geom pic]

By the similarity of $\triangle BDP$ to $\triangle PCA$, we have $\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{x}{|AB|}$, hence $|AB|=\dfrac{x^2}{y}$. Because they are the hypotenuses of right triangles, we can deduce $|BP|^2=x^2+y^2$ and $|AP|^2=\dfrac{x^4}{y^2}+x^2$. Finally, because it is the altitude of a right triangle (see [right triangle altitude formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle#Altitudes)), we have 
$$\frac1{|AP|^2}+\frac1{|BP|^2}=\frac1{|MP|^2}=\frac{1}{r^2}.$$
Hence
$$\frac1{r^2}=\frac{y^2}{x^4+x^2y^2}+\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y^2+x^2}{x^4+x^2y^2}=\frac{1}{x^2},$$

so $r=x$. This means that the locus is at least a subset of the circle centered at $P$ with radius $x$, and in fact, noting that with appropriate choice of $A$ and $B$, we can make the slope of $MP$ anything we desire except infinity, we conclude that the locus of points of $M$ is the circle centered at $P$ with radius $x$ minus the two points here labeled $C$ and $D$.